# How can I evaluate the performance of a object detector at a fixed confidence threshold?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, metric, object-detection

I have an object detector and now I have to decide which confidence threshold to use for each class. How can I determine what is the best confidence threshold for each class? Once decided, how can I evaluate this model at the given confidence threshold?

Everybody seems to just be using variations of AP (or mAP), which though evaluates the model at different confidence thresholds.